# Issue applying impulse with mouse

Tags: c++, physics, bulletphysics

I'm currently working on integrating Bullet SDK into my game engine. Currently I'm trying to apply a force to my objects using a mouse click. So far I've failed.
Here is the code that is called when an object is clicked on:

```
void PhysicsComponent::ApplyForce(glm::vec3& hitPoint, glm::vec3& direction, float amount)
{
   if (!m_body)
      return;

   m_body->activate(true);
   btVector3 force = btVector3(0, 1, 0) * amount;
   m_body->applyImpulse(force, centerOfMass);

}
```

If I use the same idea in my update() function, it works fine. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Issue had nothing to do with Bullet. I was storing my Physics Components in a vector as references and attaching &(m_physicsComponents.back()) to my Objects. Evey time the vector resized 1 object would break. I just hadn't noticed the issue until now, since the broken object happened to be what my test object was sitting on. Changed my vector to store pointers and everything works.